# XCode project suddenly failing with 'missing required module 'CgRPC'

Tags: xcode9

Dusted off an iPhone project that hasn't had changes in the past three months.  When trying to run the iPhone8 simulator, the build fails with:

`<unknown>:0: error: missing required module 'CgRPC'`

CgRPC is a dependency of the library I'm using.  When the project attempts to build, I see it building CgRPC, so am not quite sure what the problem is.

I've tried, for grins, adding explicit CgRPC as an explicit dependency, but that didn't resolve anything.

Any tips from the XCode experts out there?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what changed, but adding the CgRPC headers to the compiler search path resolved the issue.